# Module code not running correctly

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, module

I am trying to write some code to display the area of three sides, which the user selects.  If the input is incorrect, I need to display "Input is invalid". My code will not compute the area correctly or display "Input is invalid", when the input is incorrect. I could really use the help. Here is a picture of what I need done:

[image]

This is the code I have:

```
side1, side2, side3 = eval(input("Enter three sides in a double: "))

def isValid(side1, side2, side3):

    if side1 + side2 > side3 and side1 + side3 > side2 and side2 + side3 > side1: 
        return True
    else: 
        return None

def area(side1, side2, side3):

    s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;

    totalArea = (s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3)) ** 0.5    

    return totalArea

def main():

    condition = isValid(side1, side2, side3)

    totalArea = area(side1, side2, side3)

    if True:
        print("The area of the triangle is " + str(totalArea))
    else:
        print("input is invalid")

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't say `if True` because then it will always happen.  Instead, say `if condition`.  Also, in `isValid()`, you can just return the results of your check:

```
return side1 + side2 > side3 and side1 + side3 > side2 and side2 + side3 > side1
```

Your full code should look like this:

```
side1, side2, side3 = eval(input("Enter three sides in a double: "))

def isValid(side1, side2, side3):
    return side1 + side2 > side3 and side1 + side3 > side2 and side2 + side3 > side1 

def area(side1, side2, side3):

    s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;

    totalArea = (s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3)) ** 0.5    

    return totalArea

def main():

    condition = isValid(side1, side2, side3)

    totalArea = area(side1, side2, side3)

    if condition:
        print("The area of the triangle is " + str(totalArea))
    else:
        print("input is invalid")

main()
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it won't work.  Im a little confused with what your saying too.  Are you able to swap out the code and show me?

Comment: Sure.  I'll have it up in 3 minutes tops.

Comment: Thanks, it looks great! And that finally makes sense!

Comment: Would you mind marking it as the correct answer?  There should be a greyed-out check mark below the vote count.

Comment: I love how quickly you respond.  So many people would wait for an hour before noticing my comment.  At the `importing function to new file` question, you responded to my comment within the minute, and here you do it again.  It's so refreshing.

Comment: yeah, I like checking back quick when I make a post.

Comment: I would think so.  I'm the same way; just so many people aren't

Comment: Yeah, its too bad sometimes.